# Is it possible to plot model so that convolution kernel sizes also displayed in Keras?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, visualization

I want to plot Keras deep learning model but found that [plot_model](https://keras.io/visualization/) does not show convolution kernel sizes. Is it possible to show them somehow?

Comment: Have you tried a `model.summary()`?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko yes, but it prints a table.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko and there is no kernel sizes in this table too

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know it is not possible currently, but you can always adjust the code itself. Just copy the code from https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/vis_utils.py and program an additional parameter like `show_shapes` that outputs the kernel size.